# Python - match file content to a template

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm looking for a generic way in Python to create a file template and match files against it.

For example, I would like to create a report template like the one below and then match report files against it to make sure they follow the template. This example doesn't use a real template language, it's just pseudo-code to demonstrate the idea:

```
Report summary
==============

Date generated: {some_date}

{for i in [1..3]}
File: {some_file_path}file{i}.dat
   Created:                           {some_date}
   Last modified:                     {some_date}
   Size in bytes:                     {some_number}
   Number of users accessed the file: {some_number}
{end-for}

This report contains 3 files with a total size of {some_number}
```

And then a file that looks like this can match the template:

```
Report summary
==============

Date generated: July 8 2020

File: /home/myuser/file1.dat
   Created:                           June 1 2020
   Last modified:                     July 1 2020
   Size in bytes:                     2222222
   Number of users accessed the file: 500

File: /home/myuser/file2.dat
   Created:                           May 1 2020
   Last modified:                     June 15 2020
   Size in bytes:                     3333
   Number of users accessed the file: 100

File: /home/myuser/file3.dat
   Created:                           April 21 2020
   Last modified:                     July 2 2020
   Size in bytes:                     44444
   Number of users accessed the file: 20

This report contains 10 files with a total size of 2269999
```

Of course this is just an example template. I would like to to create different templates and then match different files against them.

Any way to do it in Python 3.x?

Comment: It looks like a job for Jinja.

Comment: is it possible to match a file against a template in Jinja? It looks like Jinja is more about creating a file out of a template rather then comparing the file against the template

Comment: Indeed, I doubt that Jinja have something helpful to match a file. Then I would say that you have to deploy the loop. Make a diff between the "template" and the file and see if every differences are placeholders.

Comment: got it. So there is no generic way to do this (using Jinja or any other package)?